# Invalid read of size in structure

Tags: c, struct, valgrind

I have almost same question as this one:
[Getting data from pointer in struct "Invalid read/write"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170018/getting-data-from-pointer-in-struct-invalid-read-write?newreg=b861940248524033906f7e505f83d011)

But when I tried to follow these advices I have still same Invalid read of size.

**My struct looks like this**:

```
typedef struct{
   int lenght;
   int max_lenght;
   int extract;
   int inserting;
   void** structure;
} queue_t;
```

**And my code of circular buffer:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "queue.h"

 /* creates a new queue with a given size */
queue_t* create_queue(int capacity){

    queue_t* queue = malloc (sizeof(queue_t));

    queue->lenght = 0;
    queue -> max_lenght = capacity;
    queue -> extract = 0;
    queue -> inserting = 0;
    queue -> structure = malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity);
    return queue;
}
/* deletes the queue and all allocated memory */
void delete_queue(queue_t *queue){
    free(queue->structure);
    free(queue);
}

/*
 * inserts a reference to the element into the queue
 * returns: true on success; false otherwise
 */
bool push_to_queue(queue_t* queue, void* data){
    bool succes;
    if ((queue -> max_lenght) <= (queue -> lenght)){
        succes = false;
    }
    else{
        if (queue -> inserting == queue->max_lenght){
            queue -> inserting = 0;
        }
        queue -> structure[queue -> inserting] = data;
        queue -> inserting += 1;
        queue -> lenght += 1;
        succes = true;
    }
    return succes;
}

/*
 * gets the first element from the queue and removes it from the queue
 * returns: the first element on success; NULL otherwise
 */
void* pop_from_queue(queue_t *queue){
    void* element;
    if ((queue->lenght) <= 0){
        element = NULL;
    }
    else{
        element = queue -> structure[queue-> extract];
        queue -> extract += 1;
        queue -> lenght -= 1;
        if(queue -> extract == queue -> max_lenght){
            queue -> extract = 0;
        }
    }
    return element;
}

/*
 * gets idx-th element from the queue
 * returns: the idx-th element on success; NULL otherwise
 */
void* get_from_queue(queue_t *queue, int idx){
    void* element;
    if(idx >= queue -> lenght){
        element = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if (queue -> extract + idx >= queue->max_lenght){
            element = &queue -> structure[queue->extract+idx - queue->         max_lenght];
        }
        else{
            element = &queue -> structure[queue-> extract+idx];
        }
    }
    return element;
}

/* gets number of stored elements */
int get_queue_size(queue_t *q){
    return q -> lenght;
}
```

And I'm still getting messages from valgring that I'm outside of arrays when I try to call pop_from_queue. 
For example:

```
==236== Invalid read of size 4
==236==    at 0x4009C8: pop_from_queue (queue.c:53)
==236==    by 0x400721: pop (main.c:33)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Address 0x51fc040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==236==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==236==    by 0x40073D: pop (main.c:35)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Block was alloc'd at
==236==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==236==    by 0x4008B8: create_queue (queue.c:10)
==236==    by 0x400798: main (main.c:57)
==236==
==236== Invalid read of size 8
==236==    at 0x4009DC: pop_from_queue (queue.c:57)
==236==    by 0x400721: pop (main.c:33)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Address 0x51fc050 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==236==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==236==    by 0x40073D: pop (main.c:35)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Block was alloc'd at
==236==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==236==    by 0x4008B8: create_queue (queue.c:10)
==236==    by 0x400798: main (main.c:57)
==236==
==236== Invalid read of size 4
==236==    at 0x4009E4: pop_from_queue (queue.c:57)
==236==    by 0x400721: pop (main.c:33)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Address 0x51fc048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==236==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==236==    by 0x40073D: pop (main.c:35)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Block was alloc'd at
==236==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==236==    by 0x4008B8: create_queue (queue.c:10)
==236==    by 0x400798: main (main.c:57)
==236==
==236== Invalid read of size 4
==236==    at 0x4009FB: pop_from_queue (queue.c:58)
==236==    by 0x400721: pop (main.c:33)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Address 0x51fc048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==236==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==236==    by 0x40073D: pop (main.c:35)
==236==    by 0x400817: main (main.c:78)
==236==  Block was alloc'd at
==236==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==236==    by 0x4008B8: create_queue (queue.c:10)
==236==    by 0x400798: main (main.c:57)
==236==
etc.
```

I'm a beginner to structures so I welcome any help.

**Edit:**
These errors are on lines:

```
53 if ((queue->lenght) <= 0){
57 element = queue -> structure[queue-> extract];
58 queue -> extract += 1;
59 queue -> lenght -= 1;
60 if(queue -> extract == queue -> max_lenght){
89 return q -> lenght;
```

My main method of program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

#include "queue.h"


/* allocate new integer with value a and add it to the queue */
void add(int a, queue_t *queue)
{
   int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p = a;
   bool ret = push_to_queue(queue, (void*)p);
   if (!ret) {
      // free memory on failure
      free(p);
   }
}

/* print the int value on pointer p */
void print_int(void *p)
{
   if(p != NULL){
      printf("%d\n", *((int*)p));
   } else {
      printf("NULL\n");
   }
}

/* pop from the queue, print and free the element */
void pop(queue_t *queue)
{
   void *p = pop_from_queue(queue);
   print_int(p);
   free(queue);
}

/* get i-th element and print it (do not remove them) */
void get(int idx, queue_t *queue)
{
   print_int(get_from_queue(queue, idx));
}

/* 
 * TEST PROGRAM
 * - reads commands from stdin and executes them in the queue
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n;
   /* the tested queue */
   queue_t *queue;

   // read the size of the queue
   scanf("%d", &n);
   // create queue
   queue = create_queue(n);

   while (true) {
      char s[2];
      // read one command
      int ret = scanf("%1s", s);
      if (ret != 1) {
     break;
      }

      // add command
      if (s[0] == 'a') {
     int a;
     // read the argument of the command
     ret = scanf("%d", &a);
     if (ret != 1) {
        break;
     }
     add(a, queue);
     // remove command   
      } else if (s[0] == 'r') {
     pop(queue);
     // get command  
      } else if (s[0] == 'g') {
     int a;
     // read the argument of the command
     ret = scanf("%d", &a);
     if (ret != 1) {
        break;
     }
     get(a, queue);
      }
   }

   // remove rest of the elements in the queue
   while (get_queue_size(queue)) {
      void *p = pop_from_queue(queue);
      free(p);
   }

   // free memory
   delete_queue(queue);
   queue = NULL;

   // return 0 on succes
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show how `push_to_queue()` is called.

Comment: You have some missconception what a pointer to pointer is., Your code is wrong at multiple places. Where do you allocate the sub-arrays? A pointer is not an array. About your text: We are not a debugging service, what is your **specific ** problem? What does the debugger say? See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide the main function code ?

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux: `main` is not a _method_, neither in C nor C++. And C does not support _methods_ at all.

Comment: In get_from_queue, I think you have an extra & on the two lines element = &queue.

Comment: Your worst problem is your indent style. `get_from_queue` has a lot of UB

Comment: at `pop` `free(queue);` --> `free(p);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You should post that as an answer :D

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux This is just typo.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sure, but that typo explains why valgring complains. Apart from that it looks like this code mostly works (I feel get_from_queue still does not return a pointer to the element but a pointer to the element pointer).

Comment: Oh I have tried to get it throught the valuating system and it works -_-

Comment: The nice thing about lenght is that it won't be confused with any built-in functions.

Answer (score 5):

Going through the code by eye, I see some immediate problems.

```
/* pop from the queue, print and free the element */
void pop(queue_t *queue)
{
    void *p = pop_from_queue(queue);
    print_int(p);
    free(queue);
}
```

I don't think you mean to free the whole `queue` here, but rather `p`.

---

```
void delete_queue(queue_t *queue){
    free(queue->structure);
    free(queue);
}
```

Since `queue->structure` is a list of pointers, this only frees the memory for the list. The memory it points to still needs to be freed. That can be the caller's responsibility, but it can also be offloaded onto the queue.

With a generic structure such as this, you'd usually supply the structure with a function pointer that knows how to free the memory in the queue. For a good example, look how [the initializer of GLib's pointer arrays take a destroy function](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html#g-ptr-array-new-full).

---

```
bool push_to_queue(queue_t* queue, void* data){
    bool succes;
    if ((queue -> max_lenght) <= (queue -> lenght)){
        succes = false;
    }
    else{
        if (queue -> inserting == queue->max_lenght){
            queue -> inserting = 0;
        }
        queue -> structure[queue -> inserting] = data;
        queue -> inserting += 1;
        queue -> lenght += 1;
        succes = true;
    }
    return succes;
}
```

`if ((queue -> max_lenght) <= (queue -> lenght))` is including an invalid state where `queue -> max_lenght` is *less than* `queue->lenght`. That should never happen.

It's best to check that everything is valid explicitly with an [`assert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h). This is a debugging statement that asserts something which *must* be true like `assert( queue->length <= queue->max_length )`. If it isn't, the program will crash and inform you the assert failed. Otherwise your code treats trying to insert one too many elements and already having too many elements the same.

With that assert in place at the start of `push_to_queue` you can check `if( queue->max_length == queue->length )`.

---

I'd recommend you unit test your queue library before trying to use it in a larger program.  Test each method with normal and edge cases.  For example...

```
void test_delete_queue() {
    queue_t *q = create_queue(3);

    int nums[3] = {4,5,6};
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        push_to_queue(q, &num);
    }

    delete_queue(q);
}
```

While this doesn't appear to contain any tests, it lets you know `delete_queue` doesn't segfault and running it with valgrind will detect any leaks.

As another example, while reading your code I was highly suspicious of `queue->inserting` and `queue->extracting`. It looked to me like they'll fall out of sync if you push and pop enough. So I tested it. And, to my surprise, it works! Now we're sure that's not a problem.

```
void test_push_pop() {
    queue_t *q = create_queue(3);

    int nums[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};

    /* Push twice then pop once */
    assert( push_to_queue(q, &nums[0]) );
    assert( push_to_queue(q, &nums[1]) );
    assert( (int*)pop_from_queue(q) == &nums[0] );

    /* Push and pop again */
    assert( push_to_queue(q, &nums[2]) );
    assert( (int*)pop_from_queue(q) == &nums[1] );

    /* Push one more than the max length. This should be ok
       as we've already popped twice */
    assert( push_to_queue(q, &nums[3] ) );
    assert( (int*)pop_from_queue(q) == &nums[2] );
    assert( (int*)pop_from_queue(q) == &nums[3] );

    assert( get_queue_size(q) == 0 );

    delete_queue(q);
}
```

But a similar test for `pop` wouldn't work, because it would free the whole queue.

Comment: The first point of this answer is good, but on the other points I'm afraid it's wrong.

On delete_queue, the queue does not own the data so it is not legitimate to free its content, it is the caller responsability to handle elements allocation / free.

On push_to_queue and the assert, the case where the queue is full is a valid condition where the queue just refuses to get the data inserted, there is no need for an assert there.

Comment: Adding unit tests is good, but please test something, just don't rely on valgrind to check for memory issues. And the provided code does not delete the allocated items :(

Finally, push and pop methods are sane, if you push too much push returns false, if you pop too much pop returns NULL as they both check lenght.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux I recommended the `assert` because the code checks `if( queue ->max_lenght <= queue->lenght )` but `max_lenght` should never be *less than* `lenght`, that would indicate something has gone wrong. As for deallocation, you're probably right, it should be up to the caller, I'll fix that. As for `test_delete_queue`, I don't know how you directly test memory has been freed, so it has no asserts; that's fine. It is testing that deleting doesn't segfault or something. push/pop did turn out to be sane, and now I know they are because I tested them. :)